# Angular6 export custom component using Angular Element: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements

Tags: angular6

I created a custom component and export it as a JavaScript file, following the instruction in this link (https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/angular-elements-quick-start-guide/). I included the script file into an html file.

My problem is when I open the html in the browser (Chrome), I see an error saying "The selector "app-root" did not match any elements". But when I delete
`bootstrap: [AppComponent]`,
in **app.module.ts** file, the problem will disappear.

**app.module.ts code**:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MubHK.png)

**app.component.ts**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDT9e.png)

**index.html code**

```
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
<custom-visualization></custom-visualization>
</body>
```

**my demo html code:**

```
<custom-visualization></custom-visualization>
<script src="./exportedCustoVmisualization.js"></script>
```

**Environment:**

```
Angular version: X.Y.Z
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.6.8
@schematics/angular          0.6.8
@schematics/update           0.6.8
rxjs                         6.2.1
typescript                   2.7.2
```

Answer (score 3):

`bootstrap: [AppComponent]` command bootstraps the application with `<app-root>` template. But since in the constructor you are trying to register a custom component with `<app-vote>` tag, there is a mismatch.

If you are using customElements, you dont need to have the `bootstrap: [AppComponent]` part in your @NgModule declaration. Refer to the following link for more clearer understanding: https://medium.com/@tomsu/building-web-components-with-angular-elements-746cd2a38d5b